# Stale data passing params via React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation

This should be simple but it is just not working for me.

I have a FlatList which iterates over a collection of locations.
FlatList works fine but I am not able to pass the id value via navigation.navigate to another screen.

We are using functional components.

Here is the relevant FlatList code:

```
            <FlatList
                data={locations}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
```

...

```
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={styles.items}>{item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.listitem}>{item.addressoneline}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.listitem}>{item.id}</Text>
            </View>
```

...

```
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{ width: 30 }}
                onPress={() => {
                    props.navigation.navigate('AddEditLocation', { locationId: item.id });
                }}
            >
                <Image source={edit2} style={{ width: 20, height: 20, margin: 6 }} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

In the AddEditLocation I have coded:

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        load();
        const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', load); // fire on screen load
        return unsubscribe;
    },
    [ props.navigation ]
);

function load() {
    const id = props.navigation.getParam('id'); 
    // *** id contains stale data, is not updated when clicking on different items in the list
}
```

Not sure what I am going wrong here. The id value in the AddEditLocation does not reflect the value in the row of the FlatList. If I alert the item.id value in the onPress method of the TouchableOpacity element it displays the correct item.id value so this leads me to believe it is an issue with passing params or the way we are reading the params in the destination page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `React Navigation v4` so there is an useful component called `NavigationEvents` that will handle these listeners.

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

const YourComponent = (props) => {

  const loadItem = () => {
    const id = props.navigation.getParam('id');
  }

  return (
    <MainWrapper>
      <NavigationEvents onWillFocus={loadItem} />
      <YourComponent />
    </MainWrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. After changing my code to use NavigationEvents, the parameter passing is working. I do like the much simpler NavigationEvents which according to the documentation also handled the unsubscribe for you.

Comment: Thanks @ian-vasco. I am a bit confused as the documentation indicated that the NavigationEvents event listener is the same as the imperative navigation.addListener(...) which I was using. Regardless, NavigationEvents is working for me for Thanks!

Comment: @GregHouse I understand these listener handling could be a little bit confusing, but this component makes it easier to implement and also more readable. Glad it helped, make sure to upvote and mark as the accepted answer so other users know